# getting current element in onKeydown function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i am writing a function which will be called when a key is down on keyboard how to access value of that textbox in which key is pressed.
my code is

```
function isValid(evt,that){

console.log('coming to this 1');
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
console.log(that.val());
return true;
}

$(document).on('keydown','.is_valid',isValid);
```

how to get the value of textbox which is currently getting input from keyboard ?? please guideline How to accomplish this

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest:

```
function isValid(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode,
        self = evt.target;
    console.log(self.value);
    return true;
}

$(document).on('keydown', '.is_valid', isValid);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HbbSA/1/).

So long as the event is available to the function, you can access the target of that event with the appropriately-named `event.target`. If you need that to be a jQuery object, with access to jQuery methods you can use: `$(event.target)`.

You could also use:

```
self = evt.currentTarget;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HbbSA/2/).

Or:

```
self = document.activeElement;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HbbSA/3/).

References:

- [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.activeElement).
- [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.currentTarget).
- [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target).

Comment: +1 Rocking always.  I like the way you give an insight brief of answers.  I used to follow all your answers :)

Comment: Thank you for your kind words! =)

Answer (score 0):

you can get the current element using `$(this)`

```
$(document).on('keydown','.is_valid',isValid){
alert($(this).val());

 //and  do stuff here 

}
```

Comment: I want the content after the keydown event (like keyup), this code return the old value (value before keyup)

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside the event handler will point to the targeted element

```
function isValid(evt,that){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    console.log('log', $(this).val(), charCode);
    return true;
}

$(document).on('keydown','.is_valid',isValid);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Bhnb9/)

Answer (score 0):

change `that.val()` to `$(this).val()`

```
function isValid(evt) {
    console.log('coming to this 1');
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    console.log($(this).val());   // change that to $(this)
    return true;
}

$(document).on('keydown', '.is_valid', isValid);
```

Working good.  Check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85CNR/)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to get this.  Below are three examples:

```
function isValid(evt) {
    // if you use 'this', you don't need to pass 'evt' to the function
    console.log(this.value);

    // you can reference the event target
    console.log(evt.target.value);

    // you can reference the event's current target
    console.log(evt.currentTarget.value);

    return true;
}

$(document).on('keydown', '.is_valid', isValid);
```

These will all give you the value of the textbox.

If you want to see what other options might be available, `console.log(evt);`.